# Add suggestions to python session autocomplete that appear in IPython notebook too

Tags: python, autocomplete, ipython, jupyter-notebook, readline

I'm trying to add bespoke suggestions to the interactive python tab auto complete. I found this toy example on the interweb

```
import readline, rlcompleter

addrs = ['angela@domain.com', 'michael@domain.com', 'david@test.com']

class mycompleter(rlcompleter.Completer):
    def completer(self, text, state):
        options = [x for x in addrs if x.startswith(text)]
        try:
            return options[state]
        except IndexError:
            return None

readline.set_completer(mycompleter().completer)
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

This works very nicely in python if I save it in a module and them import it. It also works in IPython if I paste it into an active session using the %paste magic.

However, I can't get it to work in an IPython Notebook, either by loading a module or by running it in a cell. I've found the ipython docs about their extension to the `readline` module but this hasn't helped. I've tried inheriting from `IPCompleter` objects, and using `rlcompete` methods etc, but this doesn't seem to have helped.

Any suggestions about how to add things to the autocomplete suggestions in a way that works in plain python and IPython Notebook

Thanks
Niall

**UPDATE:**
Ultimately, I'm looking of a way to add functionality to a module so that it can dynamically update the session autocomplete list (ideally for args for a specific set of functions so that it doesn't pollute the suggestions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it, which is not the recommended one but works.

```
def my_matches(test):
    # might want to be smarter here
    return ['angela@domain.com', 'michael@domain.com', 'david@test.com']
ip = get_ipython()
ip.Completer.matchers.append(my_matches)
# it works
```

The old ways require setting hooks, but I haven't used it and is pretty old
and could be refactored

Comment: I like the irony of being recommended an unrecommended way of doing something by a core dev :D

Comment: I'm really looking of a way to add functionality to a module so that it can dynamically update the session autocomplete list (ideally for args for a specific set of functions so that it doesn't pollute the suggestions).

Question updated to reflect this - sorry if I moved the goalposts a bit

Comment: Hum, dynamically without action of user will be hard.

Comment: Stupid SO that post comment on enter. What you are looking for is an IPython extension and is loaded with a magic. You should ask the question on IPython-dev ML or github SO is not addapted for a longer discussion.